# SSRS Report Querying SharePoint List give error "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with two datasets: Projects (ID, Project, Status) and Tasks (ID, Title, AssignedTo, Project). I have a tablix for  Tasks that references values in the Projects dataset using the Lookup function.

The report runs fine when I run it on demand. When it runs as a subscription it logs the error "An item with the same key has already been added". When I researched this error most articles referenced having different field names, but when I try changing the field names in the dataset for Projects I get the error "The field expression for the dataset 'Projects' refers to the field 'ID'. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope"

I just want a report that joins two lists and can be produced as a subscription. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a permissions issue.  When you run the report on demand it uses your account to "log on" to SharePoint. When you run a report as a subscription it uses the account which is running your SQL Server Agent service on your SSRS server.  Perhaps that account does not have enough permission to access the SharePoint lists?

Answer (score 0):

fyi, I was using a temp table to include all my select statements including a few UNION ALL
Ex: With TEMP_TABLE (name, lastname, region) as ( SELECT name, lastname, region FROM table....UNION ALL select bname,blastname,bregion FROM table2 UNION ALL ........ 
When I was calling the temp table to call all the columns for the report, I was using SELECT * from TEMP_TABLE, this was my huge error. For some reason when I called the TEMP TABLE i HAD to use each "column name" (Ex: SELECT name, lastname, region FROM TEMP_TABLE) instead of using SELECT *